# How do i get only the videos using ALAssetsLibrary

Tags: ios, alassetslibrary

I am trying to get videos present from the photo library from the following piece of code.But i also get images list.How do i get list of all videos? what am i doing wrong?

```
NSMutableArray* assetURLDictionaries = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
 xy =[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
ALAssetsLibrary *library = [[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init];

void (^assetEnumerator)( ALAsset *, NSUInteger, BOOL *) = ^(ALAsset *result, NSUInteger index, BOOL *stop) {
    if(result != nil) {
        if([[result valueForProperty:ALAssetPropertyType] isEqualToString:ALAssetTypeVideo]) {
            [assetURLDictionaries addObject:[result valueForProperty:ALAssetPropertyURLs]];

            NSLog(@"result is:%@",result);
            NSLog(@"asset URLDictionary is:%@",assetURLDictionaries);
            NSURL *url= (NSURL*) [[result defaultRepresentation]url];

            [library assetForURL:url
                     resultBlock:^(ALAsset *asset) {
                         [xy addObject:[UIImage imageWithCGImage:[[asset defaultRepresentation] fullScreenImage]]];
                         NSLog(@" xy is:%@",xy);
                         image =[ [UIImageView alloc ] initWithImage:[xy objectAtIndex:0]];
                         NSLog(@"image is:%@",image);
                     }
                    failureBlock:^(NSError *error){ NSLog(@"test:Fail"); } ];
        }
    }
};

NSMutableArray *assetGroups = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
void (^ assetGroupEnumerator) ( ALAssetsGroup *, BOOL *)= ^(ALAssetsGroup *group, BOOL *stop) {
    NSLog(@"hello");
    if(group != nil) {
        [group enumerateAssetsUsingBlock:assetEnumerator];
        [assetGroups addObject:group];
        NSLog(@"Number of assets in group :%d",[group numberOfAssets]);
        NSLog(@"asset group is:%@",assetGroups);
    }
};

assetGroups = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

[library enumerateGroupsWithTypes:ALAssetsGroupAll
                       usingBlock:assetGroupEnumerator
                     failureBlock:^(NSError *error) {NSLog(@"A problem occurred");}];
```

Answer (score 17):

You need to add an ALAssetsFilter to the group during enumeration. Here's a basic example:

```
ALAssetsLibrary* library = [[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init];

[library enumerateGroupsWithTypes:ALAssetsGroupAll usingBlock:^(ALAssetsGroup *group, BOOL *stop) {
    if (group) {
        [group setAssetsFilter:[ALAssetsFilter allVideos]];
        [group enumerateAssetsUsingBlock:^(ALAsset *asset, NSUInteger index, BOOL *stop){
            if (asset){

                NSDictionary *meta = [[asset defaultRepresentation] metadata];

            }
        }];
    }
} failureBlock:^(NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"error enumerating AssetLibrary groups %@\n", error);
}];
```

For future reference, the [available filters](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AssetsLibrary/Reference/ALAssetsFilter_Class/Reference/Reference.html) are:

```
- allPhotos
- allVideos
- allAssets
```

Comment: Note that according to the [docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AssetsLibrary/Reference/ALAssetsLibrary_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/constant_group/Types_of_Asset) `ALAssetsGroupAll` is "the same as ORing together all the group types except for `ALAssetsGroupLibrary`". If you also want iTunes, use `ALAssetsGroupAll | ALAssetsGroupLibrary` which "includes all assets that are synced from iTunes".